# Relacionamento entre classes de contextos diferentes Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com um problema ao salvar um objeto, devido ele ter relacionamento em um contexto diferente, gostaria de saber se tem uma forma resolver esse problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não existe.

Não é apenas a definição do design que importa no Entity Framework: para que todas as relações e mapeamentos funcionem corretamente, eles **precisam** estar definidos no mesmo contexto.

Não faz muito sentido, aliás, usar objetos de contextos diferentes. O contexto mapeia uma parcela do banco de dados. Se esses dados não são acessíveis por ele, e se estes dados estiverem em um lugar que fuja da sua definição, então esse mapeamento não será possível.

Reconsidere mudar seus contextos para que todos os objetos possam estar em um único contexto, considerando que há dependência entre eles.

Comment: Mas e se os contextos estiverem apontando para o mesmo banco?
Por exemplo: no contexto1 eu tiver a entidade Usuario e no contexto2
eu relacionar o Usuario com outras entidades...

Comment: Não vai funcionar. Use apenas um contexto apontando para um banco.